# Are RDS files "More Efficient" than CSV Files?

Tags: r, csv, memory

While working in R, I have made the following informal observation:

- I have noticed that I am able to import RDS files much faster compared to similar sized CSV files.
- For example, suppose I have a CSV file on my computer. If I import this CSV file into R, use the "saveRDS" command to save this file as an RDS, and then use the "readRDS" command to re-import this same file - it seems to take less time to import an RDS version of this file compared to the CSV version of this same file.

For example:

**Step 1** I create a file for my hypothesis

```
# create file (i.e. imagine this file currently exists on the computer in CSV format)

test_file = data.frame(col1 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col2 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col3 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col4 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col5 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col6 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col7 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col8 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col9 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col10 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col11 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col12 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col13 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col14 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col15 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col16 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col17 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col18 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col19 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE), col20 = sample.int(100, 1000000, replace = TRUE))
```

**Step 2:** Compare export times: (RDS is faster)

```
 start.time <- Sys.time()
 write.csv(test_file, "test_file.csv")
 end.time <- Sys.time()
 end.time - start.time

#Time difference of 28.84087 secs

 
 start.time <- Sys.time()
 saveRDS(test_file, "test_file.RDS")
 end.time <- Sys.time()
  end.time - start.time

#Time difference of 11.96845 secs
```

**Step 3:** Compare the sizes of both files: RDS is smaller (roughly 2 times)

```
#I think this in bytes?

> file.info("test_file.csv")$size
[1] 68287349


> file.info("test_file.RDS")$size
[1] 26169028

68287349/26169028
[1] 2.609472
```

**Step 4:** Compare the import times : (RDS is faster)

```
 start.time <- Sys.time()
 test = read.csv("test_file.csv")
 end.time <- Sys.time()
 end.time - start.time
#Time difference of 8.349364 secs


 start.time <- Sys.time()
 test = readRDS("test_file.RDS")
 end.time <- Sys.time()
 end.time - start.time
#Time difference of 0.59674 secs
```

Based on these measurements, it seems that RDS is the clear winner - when compared to CSV, RDS takes less time to export and import, as well as occupies less space. My naive interpretation of this is that RDS is a "native file type" for R, and therefore RDS files might have been somehow programmed to naturally run faster in R compared to CSV files - but I am not sure about this.

I was wondering if there was any factual basis to this claim (e.g. perhaps if I were to repeat this experiment again or were to attempt this experiment on larger/smaller files with different data types, the results might be different), or have I incorrectly carried out this experiment?

PS: In the future, I am planning on running Machine Learning/Statistical models on large datasets - in this regard, I am wondering if it might be more advantageous to convert the datasets to RDS and thus save time/resources?

Comment: For speed, I'd recommend the readr package. `read_csv()`, `write_csv()` . when reading with the option `lazy = TRUE`, it runs significantly faster as it doesn't read everything in the R memory, but only what you need.

Comment: olivroy : thank you for that suggestion! I never noticed the difference between read_csv() vs. read.csv() LOL! I will have to look more into this! I wonder what the "lazy = TRUE" option does? Thank you!

Comment: BTW - if I use the "readr" package - will this also make running machine learning models faster compared to the standard way? thanks!

Comment: Text files, such as `csv` must be _parsed_ for each item to arrive at a (binary, internal) representation.  Binary representation, as in `rds` files, skips that step and is generally faster, but possibly at cost of generality (cannot share an `rds` file easily with  Python, say).  The whole topic is rich and complex, in fact [R ships with one entire manual about import/output](https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-data/) which you may find helpful.

Comment: No, it won't run faster unfortunately!